# Is my budget gaming pc any good?

Tags: computer-building

Hi this will be my first build and I was wondering is it an ok build. I have a budget of £320.

Here's the build

- **CPU** - AMD Athlon X4 860K 3.7GHz Quad-Core Processor
- **CPU Cooler** - Cooler Master Hyper 103
- **Motherboard** - Gigabyte GA-F2A68HM-HD2 Micro ATX FM2+ Motherboard
- **Memory** - Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
- **Storage** - Have my own
- **Video Card** - EVGA GeForce GTX 750 Ti 2GB Superclocked Video Card
- **Case** - Aerocool VS-92 Gaming Case
- **Power Supply** - Corsair Builder 430W 80+ Bronze Certified ATX Power Supply

The total came to £318.85 all with free delivery.

Cheers Luke

Comment: I run a similar but older rig, but with an Athlon II X4 630 CPU, 8GB RAM, 240GB SSD, 2x2TB HDD, and a GeForce 750 Ti SC 2GB GDDR5 card, and 600 watt P/S. Runs most games decently at 1080p at medium to high settings without complaint, although some newer, very graphics intensive games the frame rate can get pretty bad with higher settings, but lowering the quality a little lets them run fine. I tend to play games after they have been out a year a two, but this combo will run Borderlands 2 or BL Pre-Sequel on max settings at 1920x1080 without any problems at all. Not a bad rig for the price.

Comment: @fixer1234 where is the correct place on Stackexchange to ask such questions?

Comment: Hardware recommendations http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Ctrl-alt-dlt So these type of PC build questions are now considered off-topic for Super User? I remember searching meta-stack-exchange and saw that superuser was the best choice to ask these questions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My thoughts:

**CPU** - AMD is not my personal choice and tends to be less stable and run hotter than Intel CPU's.  You can get an Intel Pentium G3258 for about the same price and get [better performance](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Pentium-G3258-vs-AMD-Athlon-X4-860K).

**CPU Cooler** -  I would actually consider instead of buying the Cooler Master Hyper 103 buying the Cooler Master Hyper 212 Evo. It has better reviews and costs about $20-$30 less. If you want to save on that entirely then you can just use the stock cooler though

**Motherboard** - No complaints.  Gigabyte is solid.

**Memory** - Maybe too much for this build.  But looking at the price it was only like $10 more for 4 more GB.  So good choice.

**Video Card** - It works (IDK what games you are running) and it will run CSGO, Dota 2 and many others at 1080p.  You could've spent around $40 more and gotten a GTX 950 and gotten [better performance](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/GeForce-GTX-950-vs-GeForce-GTX-750-Ti).  I can't complain that much though.  I know lots of people with this card.

**Case** - No complaints.  Just has to move air and mount components (and look cool)

**Power Supply** - I have a PSU from the same line (Corsair Builder 740w 80+ Bronze) and I can tell you that you **will** want a modular power supply unless you like stuffing masses of unused molex/sata cables in the bottom of your case :/  Its not even that much more expensive and saves a lot of frustration.  I am literally considering buying a new power supply just for it to be modular.

Other than that it seems to be a pretty solid build for the price :)

(Apologies for prices in USD)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look at that intel processor and yeah might have to go for the modular one and get rid off the cpu cooler because ill not overclock it.

Comment: @Luke I didn't mean get rid of the CPU cooler.  I would actually consider instead of buying the Cooler Master Hyper 103 buying the Cooler Master Hyper 212 Evo.  It has better reviews and costs about $20-$30 less.  If you want to save on that entirely then you can just use the stock cooler though

Comment: @Luke If you found my answer satisfactory then could you mark it as the answer (click the checkmark to the left of my answer).  Thanks!